# Adding TypeScript handler to TFS Build vNext Agent

Tags: tfs, xamarin, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm attempting to set up a Xamarin iOS build on an internally hosted TFS 2015 build server. We have been working with this for a few months now and have used many of the contributed build tasks on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) and written a couple of our own.

So far we have only used tasks written using NodeJs and PowerShell. The [Xamarin.iOS task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/XamariniOS) is written using TypeScript and it seems our build agents don't have the required handler for this. We get this error when trying to run a build.

> The definition for the task does not have a handler that matches any supported by this agent. Supported handlers: AzurePowerShell, AzurePowerShellHandler, PowerShell, PowerShellHandler, PowerShellExe, PowerShellExeHandler, Process, ProcessHandler

I'm not sure how to add this capability to the agents. Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't run TypeScript directly you need to build the TypeScript into JavaScript to package it in the task.  If you look at the gulp build file in the repo you will see the compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.iOS build task requires a Mac OS build agent, refer to this link for the configuration: [Xplat build agents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/xplat) 
[image]

Another reference may help: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/

Comment: Indeed. I feel a bit foolish now asking this question. It shows the lack of understanding that I had at the time. I got there on my own but big thanks for taking the time to answer this. I found this resource to be very thorough on the subject: http://www.andrewbirch.com/tech/blog/2015/8/24/setting-up-a-continuous-build-environment-for-xamarin-part-2-buildvnext